# Out of 25 Steam achievements, I can fulfill only 20 in Duels of the Planeswalker 2013. How can I get the rest?

Tags: achievements, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers, mtg-duels-of-the-planeswalkers-2013

Regarding Duels of the Planeswalker 2013, I see 25 achievements in Steam. I completed 20 of them, but I can't complete any of the five following though I met the requirements for some. Here's the list:

- **Guildmage** (*Defeat the Sepulchral Strength deck in the revenge campaign*): not done as I don't see the mentioned deck
- **Auramancer** (*Win a duel controlling at least five Auras*): done as I even built a deck specifically to get this achievement
- **Fury of the Horde** (*Win a duel controlling at least twenty creatures*): done as I even had more than 100 with the Goblin deck, and on the same game, I got the **Master of the Wild Hunt** achievement (*Win a duel controlling at least ten creatures*) plus the **Beast Within** one (*Win a duel controlling a creature with at least 10 power*)
- **Near-Death Experience** (*Win a duel with exactly 1 life*): done as I fulfilled this requirement several times already
- **Insurrection** (*Win a duel online using an expansion deck*): not done as I don't see any expansion in Steam

How can each of these achievements be done?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the game have DLC? Maybe these achievements can only be unlocked if you purchase it?

Comment: That's what I meant by "not done as I don't see any expansion in Steam".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of these achievements can be unblocked as from the *Return to Ravnica* expansion, as I already did unlock all of them since the expansion was released earlier today.

Answer (score 2):

The achievements you mentioned can be unlocked dueling ONLINE as I have unlocked Auramancer in an online battle etc.
   Completing the Expansion Campaign will unlock the Expansion Revenge Campaign. Defeating the final opponent will unlock Guildmage .